# WCF and returned object names

Tags: vb.net, wcf, namespaces

I am new to WCF and have an issue that I cannot seemto find the answer to.

I have two projects. One is a simple login application and other is a hosted IIS WCF Service (.svc) that connects to a database. Both projects are .NET 4.

The WCF service has two methods: "Administrator_Login" and "User_Login".

Whenever each of the methods are called, they execute some code respective to the method: Administrator.Login.Execute and User.Login.Execute (I am organising my code into namespaces, Administrator.Login and User.Login being the class names and Execute being the name of the method).

Both operations return a distinct "LoginOut" object that exist within the User.Login class or Administrator.Login class.

My issue is this: Although each operation is organised into namespaces on the WCF service, when I add a service reference from the client application to the service and look at the names of types of objects returned, I am seein "LoginOut and "LoginOut1".

Is there a way to reference the returned the objects in the client application returned by the WCF service by the namespace?

I am currently having to do this:

```
Dim loginOut As Service.LoginOut = Service.Administrator_Login().Execute() 
Dim loginOut As Service.LoginOut1 = Service.User_Login().Execute()
```

But I would like to be able to do:

```
Dim loginOut As Service.Administrator.Login.LoginOut = Service.Administrator_Login().Execute() 
Dim loginOut As Service.User.Login.LoginOut = Service.User_Login().Execute()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you seperate the definitions of "LoginOut" into a class library(s) and then reference that class library(s) from your client project, and update the service reference, then you should get the behavior you are looking for. If not do a configureServiceReference, click advanced and make sure "resuse types in all referenced assemblies" is selected.

Note that this is not a "pure" way to do SOA. This binds your client and webservice together in a way that may cause you trouble down the road. However I have done this myself in different small scale situations and not run into any problems.

This solution may be a bit heavy, depending on the desired behavior. It involves distributing copies of the library DLL to each client. This can be a very powerful as you are effectively  distributing behavior with your data, but might be overkill for the problem at hand.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, after selecting Reuse Types In All Reference Assemblies, the problem still exists. What is the correct approach to accomplish this? Maybe my approach is wrong.

Comment: Do you have a reference from the client to the library that defines the classes?

Comment: Also, I moved the definitions into a class library consumed by both client and WCF service and I still have this issue.

Comment: Yes. I moved all the return types to a class library and referenced that same library from the WCF and the client application. I still have the original issue and I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Is everything in the same solution? maybe you should post your service methods. Sometimes the best thing to do is to start a new solution from scratch and try to quickly get the functionality you want working. I was able to create a proof of concept for this in 5 minutes.